# Read CSV file and create new CSV file in VBScript?

Tags: csv, vbscript

I have one CSV file with invoices list to paid.

Example:

```
Account Number;Invoice Number;Amount
11111;ID11111;100.50
11111;ID22222;250.50
22222;ID33333;100.00
11111;ID44444;300.00
```

Now I want read this file and create file like this:

```
Account Number;Invoice Number;Amount
11111;ID11111, ID22222, ID44444;651.00
22222;ID33333;100.00
```

Second field have been merged and the third field summed.
But second field must have a maximum of 50 characters and next must go to next line.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: vb.net or vbscript?  they are very different.

Comment: You can use ADO to connect to CSV data and run SQL statements. You could use the SQL `GROUP BY` clause on your Account Number column to get subtotals. Listing each invoice number will be a bit trickier, though.